# User shows on Review up as established user

Tags: support

PeterJ isn't an [established](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user) user:

[image]

But on the review page he suddenly is:

[image]

Why is that?

Also: on the review page we see images of the latest reviewers. Established users don't have shadow right there:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you mean by an "established user", and I'm not sure why you would consider yourself an established user while not PeterJ. The mouse-over information is there for *every* user.

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding. I added a link to information about established users. As far as I can see, the mouseover information isn't for every user, but only for established users, users with more than 1000 rep, as can be read here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user

Comment: Seriously? You're worried that someone might be getting a bit more  "site bling" than you think they should?

Comment: For me, this is not about deserving a special effect, it's just that I see odd behaviour which isn't as the information pages states, so I submit it as a bug. That's what this meta site is for, right? Please note that PeterJ was just an example and I in no way whatsoever think he deserves littler "site bling" than me.

Comment: I wondered what I'd done to get my own post when I saw my name in the meta preview ;). Reasonable question though, I didn't know previously the hover pop-up was related to rep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be intended. The usercard is different, on the review page it appears for everyone and only shows only the user's review activity (for all users, not just sub-1k), not the full expanded profile. Compare:

On the review activity:

[image: Review usercard]

On the rest of the site:

[image: Normal usercard]

Comment: Right, my mistake. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Of note, this is also a simple matter of space conservation - using the hovercard logic lets us just display the avatars on the page rather than whole usercards.

Answer (score 4):

To clarify, that isn't the **Expanded Hover Card** that *Established Users* get, it's much more in line with the basic card that everyone has. The avatar list for each review queue is to show who is actively reviewing, so *only* the avatar is shown by default.

The **Expanded Hover Card** is only available for question and answer posts. You'll notice that you still can't see an **Expanded Hover Card** on *Non-Established Users* question and answer posts.

Comment: Right, my mistake. Thanks for the clarification and again, sorry for any misunderstanding.